# Is there a way to use scrollTo in a child view on a parent ScrollViewReader

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to use a button in a child view to scroll to a section in a parent view. In just one view, this is how this could work:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { value in
            ScrollView {
                Button("go to bottom") {
                    value.scrollTo(19)
                }
                ForEach(0..<20) { i in
                    Text("\(i)")
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                        .id(i)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is have that button in a second view, so the first is:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { value in
            ScrollView {
                ChildButton()
                ForEach(0..<20) { i in
                    Text("\(i)")
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                        .id(i)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the general (non-working) idea for the child is:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ChildButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button("go to bottom") {
            value.scrollTo(19)
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this doesn't work since ChildButton can't access 'value' or the ScrollViewReader. How do make it so I can call scrollTo() in this child view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass the `value` down to the `ChildButton`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { value in
            ScrollView {
                ChildButton(value: value) // <- HERE

                ForEach(0..<20) { i in
                    Text("\(i)")
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                        .id(i)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ChildButton: View {
    let value: ScrollViewProxy // <- HERE

    var body: some View {
        Button("go to bottom") {
            value.scrollTo(19)
        }
    }
}
```